# WebDriver dictionary of elements

Tags: selenium, dictionary, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating a list of IWebElements to access each of elements from same type, but the test works slowly when I want to access a certain element. I came with the idea to create a dictionary of elements and access each element by it's name (text that is stored in this element). I found some topics here but was unable to make them work for me. This is the way I'm accessing elements.

```
 public IWebElement OneElement
 {
     get
     {
         return this.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("oneElement"));
     }
 }
 public List<IWebElement> ListOfNames
 {
     get
     {
         return this.Driver.FindElements(By.Id("name")).ToList();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to get element by it's text and it is fast compared the list of elements as list needs to be searched till element found. it will take time if searched element is at the last position in the list. Below code will be direct fetch of particular element. Try it and let us know.

```
public IWebElement GetElementByText(String text)
{
    get
    {
        return this.Driver.FindElement(By.xpath(String.Format("//*[@id='name'][text()='{0}']",text)));
    }
}
```